# Deserialize double array

Tags: json, swift

I try to deserialize some JSON on Swift 4.2 with Codable Protocol.
My Json:

```
{  
   "status":1,
   "data":[  
      [  
         {  
            "id":"4klJeiCKTs",
            "body":"first",
            "da":"1442236233",
            "dm":"1442236233"
         },
         {  
            ...
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

my structures and code:

```
struct GetEntriesRequest: Decodable{
    var status: Int
    var data: [NestedArrayGetEntries]
}

struct NestedArrayGetEntries: Decodable{
    var elements: [GetEntriesDataFromSession]
}
struct GetEntriesDataFromSession: Decodable{
    var id: String
    var body: String
    var da: String
    var dm: String
}
...
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            do {
                let root = try decoder.decode(GetEntriesRequest.self, from: data)
                dataSession = root
            } catch { print(error) }
```

Also, I tried this struct

```
var data: [[GetEntriesDataFromSession]]
```

but without any success.

Comment: What's the output of printing the error?

Comment: @rmaddy dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Comment: That should be in your question.

Comment: this is a valid json but you should remove `...` when you use it as you may means more objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` key is a nested array and there is no `elements` key

```
 var data: [NestedArrayGetEntries]
```

with

```
var data: [[NestedArrayGetEntries]]
```

---

```
struct GetEntriesRequest: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let data: [[NestedArrayGetEntries]]
}

struct NestedArrayGetEntries: Codable {
    let id, body, da, dm: String
}
```

---

You don't also need a snakeCase here

```
  do {
      let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetEntriesRequest.self, from: data)
      dataSession = root
   } catch { 
      print(error)
   }
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: I know, but i also try without struct NestedArrayGetEntries. With a data like [[GetEntriesDataFromSession]]

Comment: you need 2 strcuts here not  3

Comment: Do you use that json as it is ?? if so then it's invalid , you have to remove `.....`

Comment: yeah,you were right,problem was in may request, Thank you